# A meta-tag "perguntas-fechadas" não seria sinônimo de "fechamento"?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

A meta-tag [perguntas-fechadas](/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas) não seria sinônimo de [fechamento](/questions/tagged/fechamento) ou tem algum uso para especifico para a [perguntas-fechadas](/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas)?

Note que a meta-tag [perguntas-fechadas](/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas) não tem wiki e nem descrição (chamado recomendação de uso), por isto não posso compreender e nem afirmar se ela equivale a meta-tag [fechamento](/questions/tagged/fechamento).

Para resumir a meta-tag [perguntas-fechadas](/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas) pode ter algum uso mais especifico útil que [fechamento](/questions/tagged/fechamento) não possa atender? Caso contrário poderíamos transforma-la em "sinônimo", o que acham?

Comment: A pergunta que não quer calar: meta-tag ou tag do meta?

Comment: @EMBarbosa pois é eu fiz esta pergunta aqui no Meta mesmo xD ... Eu pessoalmente acho que é indiferente, afinal o uso do prefixo `meta-` é algo como em palavras como metafísica, metalinguagem outros exemplos é o uso pela *DC* (mulher-maravilha, superman, batman, flash, etc) do termo meta-humano (tá, talvez mais para neologismo ou seja o que for).

Comment: Essa pergunta não cabe aqui, tem que ser feita no meta meta :D

Comment: @bigown pois é, acho que eu fiz foi no portuguese.se e não aqui :)

Comment: é que meta-tag no meu entender é uma tag que tem características "meta". Mas tag do meta, é uma tag utilizada no "meta.SOpt" e não usada no SOpt. Por exemplo, essa tag `fechamento` não está disponível no SOpt, por isso pra mim, ela é uma tag do meta. Pode até ser uma meta-tag, mas no contexto da pergunta me parece que ficaria melhor como tag do meta no título.

Comment: @EMBarbosa faz muito sentido, mas na verdade usei meta-tag por que o atalho para usa-la em postagens é `[meta-tag:debate]`, exemplo: [meta-tag:debate]

Comment: Entendi. E entendi o motivo de você ter editado o título da minha pergunta...

Answer (score 8):

Me parece que o uso correto delas é que [fechamento](/questions/tagged/fechamento) deve ser usado para o processo de fechamento em geral, é sobre o mecanismo. Já [perguntas-fechadas](/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas) é sobre... adivinha? Perguntas que foram fechadas e se deseja discutir isso.

Pra falar a verdade eu acho que aqui no meta o uso de *tags* não precisa de muita granularidade e se o uso for um pouco errado não deve ser um grande problemas, especialmente coisas mais específicas. É bom fazer o melhor possível, mas não é tão ruim quanto no site principal, até pelo volume.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, é algo que não afeta em quase nada.